# Find the nearest idetical value in terms of distance in 2d list or array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, search, multidimensional-array

Any ideas on how to make a function that finds the closest value with the same value as the starting point.

For example, if you have this list and you want to find the closest `1` to the top left corner (which is also a one).

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The closest `1` would be in the bottom left corner, then the one in the bottom middle little bit to the left (you can not go diagonaly, so that one is further away than the one in the bottom left corner). The one on the middle layer and top layer would be at equal distance from the starting point in the top left corner.

My first thought was to search for the first occuring one in the list and the limit the search boundaries from there by only searching in a restricted area. So if you have a list that is 10 by 10 and then find the first one at [0, 5], you could then restrict the search to `list[:6][:6]` so you only search a 5 by 5 list. Or if you find a `1` at [3, 0], the search could be limited to `list[:4][:4]`.

But I don't think this is the most efficient method though, so I wonder if anyone else has some ideas or could refer me to a link that explains this well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem: searching the shortest path. For this you should use a breadth-first search.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
def closest(m, x, y): # x, y is starting point
    height = len(m)
    width = len(m[0])
    frontier = [(x,y)]
    visited = set()
    while len(frontier):
        newfrontier = []
        for cell in frontier:
            if cell not in visited:
                visited.add(cell)
                x, y = cell
                for dx, dy in ((-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)):
                    newx = x + dx
                    newy = y + dy
                    neighbor = (newx, newy)
                    if newx >= 0 and newx < width and newy >= 0 and newy < height and neighbor not in visited:
                        if m[newy][newx] == 1: # bingo!
                            return neighbor
                        newfrontier.append(neighbor)
        frontier = newfrontier

m = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

print(closest(m, 0, 0)) # ----> (0, 2)
```

The coordinates are given as (x, y), so column first, then row.

Comment: thank you, you're code is very well made and it has very clear variables so I can easily understand it which I really appreciate. Thanks again